# Mysql execute pivot table query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-workbench, distinct

I have created sql fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0586e8/1

I have table called products,tags,product_tags.I want to retrieve all product tags which has searched tags

For example if i search for `Mi tag` then it should return all tags from the product which has tag `Mi Tag`

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you stacked?

Comment: @Iria.please refer sqlfiddle.i have written query but it will return only one tag .not other tags form that products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` to find the match:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.tag_name
FROM product_tags pt JOIN
     tags t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM product_tags pt2 JOIN
                   tags t2
                   ON pt2.tag_id = t2.id
              WHERE pt2.product_id = pt.product_id AND
                    t2.tag_name = 'Mi'
             );
```

This is saying:  Get me all tags where the corresponding product has a tag of "MI".

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0586e8/5) is a SQL Fiddle.